# Using the windows azure Connectthedots.io example and running into some trouble with the C# gateway.exe socket connection

Tags: c#, python, windows, sockets, azure

I am attempting to use the Connectthedots.io example, and am running the gateway.exe program on my windows 8.1 machine. I have set up a dummy device using the code from the sound meter example (https://github.com/MSOpenTech/connectthedots/blob/master/Devices/GatewayConnectedDevices/BtUSB_2_BtUART_Example/BtUSB_2_BtUART_Example.py), although replacing the reads from the USB with a random value generated (random.randint).

I run the gateway.exe, and then I run the dummy sensor python script after. The dummy sensor script says that it has connected to the socket and is sending the JSON data to the socket. The gateway does not recognize it, and is giving this errors in the logfile.

```
2015-06-03 10:55:16.8137 ERROR Error on lock: {"ClassName":"System.AggregateException","Message":"One or more errors occurred.","Data":null,"InnerException":{"NativeErrorCode":11001,"ClassName":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException","Message":"No such host is known","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)\r\n   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)\r\n   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)\r\n   at Amqp.TcpTransport.<ConnectAsync>d__5.MoveNext()","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nGetAddrInfo\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Net.Dns\nSystem.Net.IPHostEntry GetAddrInfo(System.String)","HResult":-2147467259,"Source":"System","WatsonBuckets":null},"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()\r\n   at Amqp.TcpTransport.Connect(Connection connection, Address address, Boolean noVerification)\r\n   at Amqp.Connection.Connect(SaslProfile saslProfile, Open open)\r\n   at Amqp.Connection..ctor(Address address, SaslProfile saslProfile, Open open, OnOpened onOpened)\r\n   at Amqp.Connection..ctor(Address address)\r\n   at Microsoft.ConnectTheDots.Gateway.AMQPSender`1.ReliableSender.EstablishSender() in c:\\Users\\Cameron\\Desktop\\connectthedots-master\\Devices\\Gateways\\GatewayService\\Gateway\\Utils\\MessageSender\\AMQPSender.cs:line 129","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nThrowIfExceptional\nmscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Threading.Tasks.Task\nVoid ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean)","HResult":-2146233088,"Source":"mscorlib","WatsonBuckets":null,"InnerExceptions":[{"NativeErrorCode":11001,"ClassName":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException","Message":"No such host is known","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)\r\n   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)\r\n   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)\r\n   at Amqp.TcpTransport.<ConnectAsync>d__5.MoveNext()","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nGetAddrInfo\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Net.Dns\nSystem.Net.IPHostEntry GetAddrInfo(System.String)","HResult":-2147467259,"Source":"System","WatsonBuckets":null}]}
2015-06-03 10:55:16.8414 ERROR Exception on sendObject reference not set to an instance of an object.
2015-06-03 10:55:16.8999 ERROR Error on lock: {"ClassName":"System.AggregateException","Message":"One or more errors occurred.","Data":null,"InnerException":{"NativeErrorCode":11001,"ClassName":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException","Message":"No such host is known","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)\r\n   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)\r\n   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)\r\n   at Amqp.TcpTransport.<ConnectAsync>d__5.MoveNext()","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nGetAddrInfo\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Net.Dns\nSystem.Net.IPHostEntry GetAddrInfo(System.String)","HResult":-2147467259,"Source":"System","WatsonBuckets":null},"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()\r\n   at Amqp.TcpTransport.Connect(Connection connection, Address address, Boolean noVerification)\r\n   at Amqp.Connection.Connect(SaslProfile saslProfile, Open open)\r\n   at Amqp.Connection..ctor(Address address, SaslProfile saslProfile, Open open, OnOpened onOpened)\r\n   at Amqp.Connection..ctor(Address address)\r\n   at Microsoft.ConnectTheDots.Gateway.AMQPSender`1.ReliableSender.EstablishSender() in c:\\Users\\Cameron\\Desktop\\connectthedots-master\\Devices\\Gateways\\GatewayService\\Gateway\\Utils\\MessageSender\\AMQPSender.cs:line 129","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nThrowIfExceptional\nmscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Threading.Tasks.Task\nVoid ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean)","HResult":-2146233088,"Source":"mscorlib","WatsonBuckets":null,"InnerExceptions":[{"NativeErrorCode":11001,"ClassName":"System.Net.Sockets.SocketException","Message":"No such host is known","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)\r\n   at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean includeIPv6)\r\n   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)\r\n   at Amqp.TcpTransport.<ConnectAsync>d__5.MoveNext()","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nGetAddrInfo\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Net.Dns\nSystem.Net.IPHostEntry GetAddrInfo(System.String)","HResult":-2147467259,"Source":"System","WatsonBuckets":null}]}
2015-06-03 10:55:16.9280 ERROR Exception on sendObject reference not set to an instance of an object.
2015-06-03 10:55:16.9553 ERROR Exception in task:    at Microsoft.ConnectTheDots.Gateway.AMQPSender`1.SendAmqpMessage(Message m) in c:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\connectthedots-master\Devices\Gateways\GatewayService\Gateway\Utils\MessageSender\AMQPSender.cs:line 355
   at Microsoft.ConnectTheDots.Gateway.AMQPSender`1.<PrepareAndSend>b__0(Message m) in c:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\connectthedots-master\Devices\Gateways\GatewayService\Gateway\Utils\MessageSender\AMQPSender.cs:line 324
   at Microsoft.ConnectTheDots.Common.SafeAction`1.SafeInvoke(TParam obj) in c:\Users\Cameron\Desktop\connectthedots-master\Devices\Gateways\GatewayService\Common\SafeAction.cs:line 48
2015-06-03 10:55:16.9553 ERROR Message in task: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Why is this not working? Is it due to some incompatibility on windows? Because I have not modified the C# gateway code whatsoever, and my dummy sensor appears to be connecting and sending the data, so what gives? I would imagine the example given by Microsoft would run on Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 0):

May I know whether you got the error messages from the log file (connectthedots-master\Devices\Gateways\GatewayService\WindowsEXE\bin\Debug\logs) or not? Based on my understanding, it looks like the issue is encountered because of you have not set the values of AMQPServiceConfig in app.config (GatewayExe) correctly.
[image]

Per my experience you have two options to get the values from Azure Event Hubs:

**Option1**

Leverage AzurePrep project in code sample to generate the log file which contains the info like this:
[image]

Then use below format to replace the info in app.config in Microsoft.ConnectTheDots.GatewayExe project.

> AMQPSAddress="amqps://[key-name]:[key]@[namespace].servicebus.windows.net"

**Option2**

1. Browse http://manage.windowsazure.com
2. Selecting Service Bus in the left nav menu
3. Picking your Namespace
4. Select Event Hubs from the top menu -> select ehdevices -> select Connection Information tab at the bottom

Then use below format to replace the info in app.config

> AMQPSAddress="amqps://[key-name]:[key]@[namespace].servicebus.windows.net"

Since I couldn’t fully reproduce your issue on my side, some other tips for your reference in case I may miss anything for understanding your issue

- Please use ‘run as administrator’ for VS when you set up the
  Gateway Service, otherwise the service wouldn’t listen to the port
  which receives the requests from BtUSB_2_BtUART_Example Python
  script.
- Use Python2 instead of Python3 since some grammars have    difference
  in Python3, otherwise you may need to modify the code in BtUSB_2_BtUART_Example.py file

Blow is the code sample running results on my side and I could see figures on my Azure portal – ehdevices dashboard.
[image]
[image]